# Is there a way to store the value of a XML-Tag inside a Tag attribute

Tags: xslt

im trying to make a xslt-stylesheet that trasnforms a xml Document into another xml Document and applies some filters. Im having specially the issue that im trying to acess a value that is stored inside a Tag (Name_BLANK_of_BLANK_programmer) and i want it to store into a tag attribute(Testplan name=" HERE COMES THE VALUE ").

I want to transform this=

```
<Testplan>
<Name_BLANK_of_BLANK_programmer>136 - MEL 1 S -  24 DC</Name_BLANK_of_BLANK_programmer>
<BlackboxType>0</BlackboxType>
<ShowTestStepGrafics>0</ShowTestStepGrafics>
```

into this=

```
<Testplan number="136 - MEL 1 S -  24 DC">
<Instruction>3500</Instruction>
<Steps>
```

Comment: Probably same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571209/how-to-add-root-element-as-a-attribute-using-xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havn't upload proper input and desire output so as i assumed and suggest that you can do like this, see [link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9R):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template  match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Testplan">
        <Testplan number="{Name_BLANK_of_BLANK_programmer}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except Name_BLANK_of_BLANK_programmer"/>
        </Testplan>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but `except` requires XSLT 2.0: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9R/1

Comment: @AndreasMaita if its help you to solve your problem, Please accept this answer. Thanks!